# Bounding $l^0$ norm of random quantity

Tags: pr.probability

There are many techniques in high dimensional probability for bounding quantities of the form

$$ \mathbf{E}( \sup_{s \in S} X_s ) $$

where $\{ X_s \}$ are a family of random variables which are not independent. In my research, I have run into a problem in the complete opposite direction i.e. bounding quantities of the form

$$ \mathbf{E}( \# \{ s \in S : X_s \neq 0 \}| ). $$

If we view the first equation as a bound on an $l^\infty$ norm of the family $\{ X_s \}$, then the second equation can be viewed as a bound on the ''$l^0$ norm'' of the family $\{ X_s \}$. What kind of techniques are there to bound quantities of this form? Is there perhaps a kind of `duality' result that enables us to study one result in terms of the other?

Comment: I don't understand. Is it correct that you want bounds for $\sum_{s \in S} \mathbb{P}(X_s \not= 0)$?

Comment: If $S$ is finite this seems like the best option, but say, if $\{ X_s \}$ was indexed for $s \in \mathbf{R}^d$ then measuring the Lebesgue measure of the set of $s$ such that $X_s \neq 0$ rather than the cardinality becomes important. I've edited the question to simplify the situation.

Comment: Your edit hasn't changed anything. We have quite formally $\mathbb{E}(|\{s \in S \colon X_s \not= 0\}|) = \sum_{s \in S} \mathbb{P}(X_s \not= 0)$. You need a different expression which has the meaning you intend. It's difficult (at least for me) to guess what your intention is.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much in terms of high dimensional probability (though this is definitely a high dimensional probability question).
I suspect however that you meant a slightly different question, which I answer below.

If $S$ is a subset of $R$ and $X$ is say a Gaussian process then the [Kac-Rice formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_formula)
allows you to compute $E\{\#s: X_s=0\})$ (the number with $\neq 0$ will be typically infinity if the marginal has a density). Dito if $S$ is a subset of $R^k$ and $X$ is a $k$-dimensional vector. Kac-Rice is not limited to the Gaussian setup, but the latter simplifies the computation.

Note that in the one dimensional case, if $X$ is very irregular (e.g., Brownian motion) then the expectation above is $\infty$.

If you really meant what you asked, then in case $P(X_s=0)<1$ and $S$ is one dimensional of positive Lebesgue measure, the answer is $\infty$ by Fubini.